# Design Question on Android Adapters

Tags: android, listener, listactivity, addeventlistener

Should I create a Listener within a BaseAdapter or should I pass it in?

I have 4 classes that inherit from a base class. I pass the Adapter a list objects. The Adapter is eventually used with a ListActivity

I want to create a View based on the derived class and I want them to launch an Activity based on the type of a View.

Currently I create the intent and Listener in the BaseAdapter. Is what I'm doing a good pratice?

Comment: I'm having a hard time following what you're trying to do. What type of object is the base class? What are the 4 subclasses? Is the Adapter having to deal with these subclasses or what? What do you want the Listeners to do?

Comment: "Should I create a Listener within a BaseAdapter or should I pass it in?" -- a "listener" for...what?

Comment: I have a ListView. Each line in the ListView is 1 of 4 types. When I click on any line I expect to see a new activity launch. I'm trying to figure out the best place to put the logic for deciding  which activity to launch. Should I do it in the ListActivity e.g. onCreate() or should I put that logic in an Adapter that I have extended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29) has a very cool callback,

```
onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
```

Instead of creating the Listeners/Intents in my adapter and so on, I simply override that function in the ListActivity to decide with activity I need to launch!